# How to add a single smooth line with multiple CGPoint Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have this function that takes an `Array[CGPoint]` and I am trying to create a single trend. I can't get it to be a smooth line through the array of points, when I use the `moveToPoint()` function after each point, I get this black line in the background. This is my code and images of the output:

```
class func drawLineThroughPoint(start : CGPoint, throughPoint through: [CGPoint], endPoint end:CGPoint, ofColor lineColor: UIColor, inView view:UIView) {

    //design the path
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(start)
    for (_, point) in EnumerateSequence(through) {
        path.addLineToPoint(point)
        //path.moveToPoint(point) MARK: See image with moveToPoint
        path.moveToPoint(point) //MARK: See image without moveToPoint
    }
    path.addLineToPoint(end)

    //design path in layer
    //design path in layer
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.CGColor
    shapeLayer.shadowColor = lineColor.CGColor
    shapeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.95
    shapeLayer.shadowRadius = 5
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

> With path.moveToPoint()

[image: Without path.moveToPoint()]

> Without path.moveToPoint()

[image: With path.moveToPoint()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Without the `moveToPoint` in the for loop is the correct approach.

If you use `moveToPoint` in the for loop, you're creating a new line segment for each section of the path, hence why it looked disconnected.

Your "*black line in the background*" in the first image is just the `CAShapeLayer` trying to fill the area covered by the path.

You can remedy this by simply setting the `fillColor` of the `CAShapeLayer` to `clearColor`.

```
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
```

**This gives me the following result:**

[image]

Comment: Works! thank.. I did accidently misspelled my image, this is fixed. How would you get the corners rounded?

Comment: @TalZion set the `lineJoin` of the `CAShapeLayer` to `kCALineJoinRound`

Comment: Not working, tried this shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound and also tried path.lineJoinStyle = .Round but still not round

Comment: @TalZion hmm, weird. [Working fine](https://infinit.io/_/y9RQmti) for me with [this code](https://infinit.io/_/fw8rQJh)! Try cleaning your build folder. Are you also talking about the line ends? In that case you also want to set the `lineCap` to `kCALineCapRound`. And no, you can't do it on the path - that only works if you're using the `stroke()` function on the path itself.

Comment: Strange, see my updated code, I get the line ends to be rounded, but not the lin join

Comment: @TalZion do you still have `path.moveToPoint(point)` in your for loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105593/discussion-between-originaluser2-and-tal-zion).

Answer (score 0):

Change the lineJoinStyle property of your path or use the addCurveToPoint: method.